# MySQL Query suggestion with access id

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table like this

```
ownerlisting_access_id   property_id    mainaccess_id   subaccess_id access_value
 62                      2              35      41           Yes
 64                      2              35      36           Yes
123                      4              35      41       Yes
125                      4              35      36       Yes
306                      7              35      41       Yes
307                      7              35      42       Yes
308                      7              35      36       Yes
```

I want a query that will give me this output using subaccess_id(41,42,36) and mainaccess_id(35) -

```
ownerlisting_access_id   property_id    mainaccess_id   subaccess_id    access_value
 306                     7              35              41              Yes
 307                     7              35              42              Yes
 308                     7              35              36              Yes
```

I need to get the property_id  as 7 using sub access id with 41, 42, 36

Comment: What is the problem you are facing in the query you have written? Please show us your query.

Comment: SELECT * FROM `rt_ownerlisting_access` WHERE `mainaccess_id` = 35 AND (`subaccess_id` = 41 OR `subaccess_id` = 42 OR `subaccess_id` = 36 )

I am getting all records

SELECT * FROM `rt_ownerlisting_access` WHERE `mainaccess_id` = 35 AND (`subaccess_id` = 41 AND `subaccess_id` = 42 AND `subaccess_id` = 36 )

I am getting no records

Comment: It should return all records because all your records have subaccess_id = 41, 42, or 36.

Comment: @mikejohnvino. You want the MAX(property_id) for each duplicate?

Comment: 42 is not in the property_id 2 & 4 . but I am getting these property_id also in the result

Comment: Now you have specified the condition which can help us in giving you a better query that works for you. Till now it was not clear what you wanted. I have added an answer for you.

Answer (score 1):

The fastest way to get an answer to your question is to describe the PROBLEM not just show results you need. It's not clear what is the logic behind your desired output. I guess you need the rows with the highest `property_id` for each group `subaccess_id`. If so here is the query:

```
select * from t 
join (select subaccess_id, max(property_id) MAX_property_id 
        from t 
        where mainaccess_id=35
              and 
              subaccess_id in (41,42,36) 
        group by subaccess_id
      ) t1
      on t.subaccess_id=t1.subaccess_id
         and 
         t.property_id=t1.MAX_property_id
```

<kbd>[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/51a7e/2)</kbd>

Also here is a query that outputs results you needed :) But I guess it doesn't solve your PROBLEM:

```
select * from t where property_id=7
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT table1.* FROM (
select property_id, group_concat(DISTINCT subaccess_id ORDER BY subaccess_id) as list
from table1 as t1 group by property_id
  ) a, table1
WHERE a.property_id = table1.property_id
AND a.list = '36,41,42'
```

Working query: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4744ea/2

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT MAX(DISTINCT property_ID) AS property_ID, mainaccess_id, 
MAX(DISTINCT subaccess_id) AS subaccess_id, MAX(DISTINCT access_value) 
FROM tableName GROUP BY mainaccess_id ORDER BY  mainaccess_id
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT property_ID, mainaccess_id, subaccess_id, access_value
FROM tableName t1
WHERE t1.mainaccess_id = 35 
AND (t1.subaccess_id = 41 OR t1.subaccess_id = 42 OR t1.subaccess_id = 36)
AND t1.property_ID = (SELECT MAX(t2.property_ID)
                    FROM tableName t2
                    WHERE t2.mainaccess_id = 35 
                    AND (t2.subaccess_id = 41 OR t2.subaccess_id = 42 OR t2.subaccess_id = 36))
```

Comment: I guessed property_id = 7 was not known?